# Using NetTcpBinding to communicate with non-WCF clients

Tags: wcf, web-services

`NetTcpBinding` is used for WCF to WCF communication. But could it also be used for communication with non-WCF clients? Namely, it does use several of `WS-*` protocols, so is there a particular reason why it wouldn’t be able to communicate with non-WCF clients?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NetTcpBinding` is not interoperable. It will only work with other WCF clients. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) article for more information.

Comment: But what is the reason that it can't be used for communication with non-WCF clients?

Comment: Which binding would they use? How would they know to use it? What would the WSDL say?

Comment: I believe that how the SOAP messages are encoded limits using this binding with WCF clients only, but I could be wrong. Generally, one would use WsHttpBinding for interoperability with non-WCF clients.