# Consume WCF from Java client hosted on Linux server

Tags: java, linux, wcf, tcp, named-pipes

Can WCF service hosted as TCP IP or Named Pipes on windows server be consumed by Java based application hosted on linux server?

I have a wcf service which requires low latency and very high calls per day. Hosting the service on IIS is not an option due to performance issues and HTTP overhead. This service needs to be consumed by java based client hosted on linux server. Can it be consumed by Java client if it is hosted on TCP end-point? Looks like Named Pipes are only allowed within the same machines so it wont fit the requirements too.

Comment: Short answer ? Yes. I think you need to provide more details....

Comment: I have a wcf service which requires low latency and very high calls per day. Hosting the service on IIS is not an option due to performance issues and HTTP overhead. This service needs to be consumed by java based client hosted on linux server. Can it be consumed by JavaClient if it is hosted on TCP end-point? Looks like Named Pipes are only allowed within the same machines so it wont fit the requirements too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only binding that assures "interoperability" in WCF is `BasicHttpBinding`.
If you need minimum overload don't use WCF. 
Write your own tcp based protocol, use sockets or whatever you like.

[Here is answer to very similiar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188318/using-nettcpbinding-to-communicate-with-non-wcf-clients)